# Set PAC (Proxy Auto-Config) file via bash?

Tags: command-line, proxy

All the info I have found online deals with the gui network manager. How do I set this value via terminal?

Answer (score 7):

A PAC file needs to be interpreted with javascript. The majority (if not all) programs that make use of the http_proxy environment variable will not be able to interpret this file in order to make user of it.

The only approach that seems suitable is if you find or make a program that will interpret the javascript found in a PAC file and use the returned values for setting http_proxy. However, the idea is more that this is done dynamically for each URL, so this approach will not work nicely.

If all you want is to set the value that is used within gnome from the command line, then you can do this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode auto
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url 'http://my.prox.org/foo.pac'
```

To unset:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''                   
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode none
```

You can find further information here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/Proxies

Comment: worked nicely for me.